# Bootstrap and/or media queries not working on Github Pages

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, github-pages

I want to host a website using **GitHub Pages**. I was able to upload it, and it works perfectly on a computer. However, when I open it on a phone the Bootstrap and/or media queries is not working, because the website looks like its shrink to fit, instead of taking the responsive layout I coded.

Right now my files look like:

index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
<!-- JS (end of body) -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```

responsive.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
.header-picture{
    display: none;
}
```

The problem is that on my phone the website looks like this: [non-responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnd54.png)

When it should look like this (according to responsinator): [responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phORc.png)

I followed 
[Bootstrap / CSS not working on Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205310/bootstrap-css-not-working-on-github-pages?rq=1)
and tried to fix it by adding the file location on github. However, I got the same result

index.html

```
<!-- Meta tag for responsive websites -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://EmiliaPaz.github.io/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://EmiliaPaz.github.io/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://EmiliaPaz.github.io/css/responsive.css">
<!-- JS-->
<script src="https://EmiliaPaz.github.io/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://EmiliaPaz.github.io/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://EmiliaPaz.github.io/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://EmiliaPaz.github.io/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```

What I find really curious is that when I put my website URL (https://emiliapaz.github.io/) on responsinator.com , it shows that it should work on smaller screens but it doesnt!

Thanks for the help, I am really stuck

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo with your `<meta>` tags (`width-device-width`).

Change from:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta viewport needs to fit the device width on safari IOS.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

For More Info Reference Stack Question below: 
[What is initial scale, user-scalable, minimum-scale, maximum-scale attribute in meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in)